# React/MUI useState variables getting reset to defaults after I make an API call

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

So I have a component "Job" that renders some input fields. One the field is with search icon (I used `endAdorment` with icon) using which rest of the fields could be populated.  I am storing the state with `useState` hook and everything works as expected when I am tying in the fields. The state is preserved as expected.

`onChange` on the search icon makes the call back makes API call to backend and returns the values which I am setting in the `state`  `values`

Here is my snippet:

```
const custDetails = {
  vehicle: "",
  mobile: "",
  email: "",
  name: "",
  address: "",
  alt_mobile: "",
};

export default function Job() {
  const customerURL = "http://localhost:3001/api/v1/findCustomer";
  const { values, setvalues, handleChange } = useForm(custDetails);

  const fetchCustomer = async (vehicle) => {
    return await axios
      .post(customerURL, {
        input_type: "vehicle",
        search_key: vehicle,
      })
      .then((res) => res.data);
  };

  const findCustomer = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    fetchCustomer(values.vehicle).then((data) => {
      setvalues(data);
    });
  };

  return (
    <StyledBox border={1}>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <CustomField
            value={values.vehicle}
            onChange={handleChange}
            label="Vehicle No"
            name="vehicle"
            InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <IconButton>
                  <SearchOutlined onClick={findCustomer} />
                </IconButton>
              ),
            }}
          />
          <CustomField
            label="Customer Email"
            name="email"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.email}
          />
          <CustomField
            label="Customer Address"
            name="address"
            multiline
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.address}
            maxRows={4}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={6}>
          <CustomField
            variant="outlined"
            label="Mobile No"
            name="mobile"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.mobile}
          />
          <CustomField
            label="Customer Name"
            name="name"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.name}
          />
          <CustomField
            label="Alternate Mobile"
            name="alt_mobile"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.alt_mobile}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </StyledBox>
  );
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VS2AB.png) Here is the empty fields

useForm is standard form template:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

export function useForm(initialValues) {

    const [values, setvalues] = useState(initialValues);

    const handleChange = e => {
        const { name, value } = e.target
        setvalues({
            ...values,
            [name]: value
        })
    }

  return {
    values,
    setvalues,
    handleChange,
  }
}
```

When I am searching using the icon, the values found from the API are displayed on the form as expected. But the state `values` is getting reset to initial "null" values. I want to preserve the state `values` as I will be using it later as part of different requirement. I think it is related to the way I am calling backend API.

Any suggestions what I am doing incorrectly here? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So I figured that the `state` values does not gets reflected immediately after making an API call. The correct way to make sure state is updated before using it in subsequent calls is to use the useEffect technique as outlined in a related question:

[The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).